# component backend menu with variable

Tags: joomla

How to create backend menu link with variable e.g. userID to own component?

I know that is possible to make xml file in view but how to insert variable there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For your front ent component you will aslo add its backend component. Links in Joomla 1.5 are normally managed in the MySQL table called jos_components. Take a look at the fields in jos components called: link,menuid,parent,admin_menu_link, admin_menu_alt.

Comment: I'm about links that you can add to my own frontpage menu